# cannot start a python multiprocessing.Process twice

Tags: python, opencv, python-multiprocessing

Below given is my code. I am trying to scan barcodes and display it using OpenCV. The program works well but there is a huge lag in fps when grabbing frames from drone camera as RTMP stream. Due to the same I am trying to use multi processing method.

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol
import time 
import multiprocessing 
global frame
def barcode(frame):
    for barcode in decode(frame, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.CODE128]):
        myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
        cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255,0,255),5)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        akash = []
        akash.append(myData)
        cv2.putText(frame, myData, (pts2[0], pts2[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255,99,71), 2)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = barcode)        

cv2.namedWindow("Result", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(True):
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        if frame is not None:
            p1.start()   
            cv2.imshow('Result',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
vid.release()
vid.destroyAllWindows()
```

and the error is

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-df50d7c70cda> in <module>
     27         ret, frame = vid.read()
     28         if frame is not None:
---> 29             p1.start()
     30             cv2.imshow('Result',frame)
     31         if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py in start(self)
    113         '''
    114         self._check_closed()
--> 115         assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
    116         assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), \
    117                'can only start a process object created by current process'

AssertionError: cannot start a process twice
```

Comment: fundamental issues in your understanding of concurrency/parallelism. I see at least one other issue with that piece of code you might not have noticed yet. -- strip it all down to just reading the stream. is that, *just that*, fast and low-latency enough?

Comment: Yeah, when I remove the barcode decoding part it seems to work faster.

Comment: Is there any way that I can do this using multiprocessing?

Comment: ok good. now, whether you use multiprocessing or threading (`Thread`) will make no practical difference, except threads would need less system resources. the issue here is that you have *one* Process object. if you need several, create several. if you need a process/thread that reads from a queue and returns results through another queue, you can do that instead.

Comment: there's a concurrency issue with your code (supposing what you intend to do would work). in `barcode()` you write to `frame`, while in the main loop, you are concurrently trying to `imshow` it. by chance, what you want to draw will show up or not, depending on which process is getting to the data faster. -- what you should do is use a **pool** of workers (threads), a work queue (put fresh frames in there), and a result queue (a worker draws on its frame and puts it in that queue). the main loop reads from the result queue and displays the frames. -- you'll need another thread to read VideoCap

Comment: perhaps look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit

Answer (score 1):

Try not to create **processes** inside loops. The best way to use processes is to create **n processes outside** and then, with the help of **Queues**, access and push data.

- In the following code, I created 5 processes which would run infinitely and try to fetch data from **inQ** queue.
- Then do all the processing that you were doing.
- After that, I'm pushing it to **outQ** queue, which we'll use later to show the results.
- In the main, I am simply reading the data from the opencv **vid** object and the pushing to the **inQ** which our Processes will use to fetch frame.
- Next, I'm just fetching the results. This way appears better to me as we don't have to create processes in every iteration as well as we have multiple processes ready to process the data at all times.
  You can also set the **buffer limit** for the queue if you want. Also, with live streams, try to have a **skipFrame** parameter to skip a few frames. That would boost up the fps.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol
import time 
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

inQ = Queue()
outQ = Queue()


def barcode():
    global inQ
    global outQ
    try:
        print("Solving..")
        frame = inQ.get()
        for barcode in decode(frame, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.CODE128]):
            myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
            pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
            pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
            cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255,0,255),5)
            pts2 = barcode.rect
            akash = []
            akash.append(myData)
            cv2.putText(frame, myData, (pts2[0], pts2[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255,99,71), 2)

            outQ.put(frame)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


for _ in range(5):  # configure yourself      
    Process(target = barcode).start()        

cv2.namedWindow("Result", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Inside main")
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while vid.isOpened():
        print("While...")
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        if ret:
            try:
                inQ.put(frame)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        try:
            output = outQ.get()
            cv2.imshow("Result", output)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    vid.release()
    vid.destroyAllWindows()
```